# Swagger Is not able to produce documentation for HTTP "PATCH"

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I Have followed the below 
blog entry:
[http://kingsfleet.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/transparent-patch-support-in-jax-rs-20.html](http://Transparent%20PATCH%20support%20in%20JAX-RS%202.0) 
[https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.6/examples/http-patch](http://Sample%20Http%20Patch%20in%20jersey)

To create end point to support HTTP "PATCH" method in Jersey 2.6
Dependency Versions:

```
-Jersey: 2.6
-swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10: 1.3.12
```

**Question?**
Why `Patch` end point is not getting listed as part of the swagger ui documentation?

**Analysis:**

If I am annotating with this annotation, then documentation for that end point getting generated, but no interaction .

```
@com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.PATCH
```

**Configurations**

```
JerssyApplicationInitializer

packages(true, "com.test.account.endpoint", "com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.json");
        //Swagger Configuration
        register(new ApiListingResourceJSON(), 10);
        register(JerseyApiDeclarationProvider.class);
        register(JerseyResourceListingProvider.class);

        //Genson Converter
        register(GensonJsonConverter.class, 1);
        register(createMoxyJsonResolver());
```

I am not sure, if I am missing something, any help or guide will be helpful.

Patch method doscumets:

```
 public static final String PATCH_MEDIA_TYPE = "application/json-patch+json";
    @PATCH
        //@com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.PATCH
        @PreAuthorize(userAuthenticationRequire=true)
        @Consumes(PATCH_MEDIA_TYPE)
        @Path("{id: .\\d+}")
        @ApiOperation(value = "Update Client Details in UIM System."
                    , response = State.class
                    , notes="Requesting User, should be the owner of the Client."
                    , consumes = PATCH_MEDIA_TYPE)
        @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(code = _401, message = "If the access token is invalid.", response = String.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = _498, message = "If the access token is expired.", response = String.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = _420, message = "If Provided Input is not valid according to requirment specification."),
            @ApiResponse(code = _404, message = "If no client/app Found."),
            @ApiResponse(code = _200, message = "If Client Account has been Updated successfully. ", response=String.class)
        })
        public State updateClientDetails(@ApiParam(value="Client Id to be Updated.", required=true) @PathParam(CLIENT_ID) String clientId
                , @ApiParam(value = "Updated field and Value.", required = true) final State newState){
            //LOG.info("[ENTRY]- Received requst for updating Client {} from System.", clientId);
            System.out.println("----->" + someBean.test());
            //LOG.info("[EXIT]- Client Id {} Updation has been completed.", clientId);
            Test t = new Test();
            t.name = "Hello Test";
            System.out.println(t.name);
            return newState;
        }
```

Comment: When you say it is not generated, do you look at the UI or the generated Swagger JSON?

Comment: Can you edit the question with a sample method signature including its annotations?

Comment: @Ron Hmm edited, please have a look...Thanks for giving your time :)

Comment: Two more questions - Is the resource annotated with @Api? Which version of swagger-core do you use?

Comment: @Ron: Yes it has @Api(value = CLIENT_PATH, description = "Client Managment such as Register, read, update and delete") intact its producing document for other method like GET, DELETE present inside. version=1.3.12
artifactId=swagger-core_2.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your index.html.  That controls which HTTP operations are interactive--by changing it to this:

```
  window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    url: url,
    dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
    supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
```

You will have interaction on the PATCH method:

[image]

Comment: Thank you..Its indeed a fix in terms of swagger-ui to support @com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.PATCH, here are two questions, why custom Patch annotation is not working? As I am following Jsonpatch (RFC 6902), then when sending body as part of  Patch request, I should be sending similar to this "[{"op" : "replace","path" : "/message","value" : "patchedMessage"}]" which can't be mapped to the resource, so any fix in that front?

Comment: When I talk about custom Patch annotation its like https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.6/examples/http-patch/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/httppatch/PATCH.java

Comment: Swagger scans for com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.PATCH only, when we wrote that, there was no PATCH annotation in jersey.  If you want to support a custom patch behavior, you'll have to do that on the server.  Add both annotations for now (jersey and com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.PATCH) and it should work.  I'll be adding a ticket to add scanning support for org.glassfish.jersey.examples.httppatch.PATCH

Comment: Thank you, I added two of them and from custom one removed @HttpMethod("PATCH")..

Comment: Jayaram do you have it working now?  I have opened this issue to track it:  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/876

Comment: Hmm its ....its coincidence that before you post the comment yesterday I was trying with the same approach..now all smooth..Thanks a lot again :)..off the topic, is that possible to add ApiParm as json-patch compatible, here I mean method signature will be as taking argument as normal bean, where as user will enter the request body as like [{"op" : "replace","path" : "/message","value" : "patcheMessage"}], I mean following the specification of RFC 6902

Comment: Please note that the Patch support has been committed and will be in 1.5.2-M1