# Swagger not creating PATCH API

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, http-patch

I have a simple API in spring boot using JpaRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {...}
```

I'm able to create a user using `POST` API:

```
curl localhost:8080/users -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"firstName": "Alik", "lastName": "Elzin", "username": "kilaka"}'
```

I'm also able update one of the fields of a user using PATCH:

```
curl localhost:8080/users/1 -i -X PATCH -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"firstName": "Alikuki"}'
```

Swagger config:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

When using swagger to create the API as UI, I see the `POST` option and also a `PUT` option, but not the working `PATCH` API. See screecap below.

**Any idea how I can make swagger generate the PATCH API?**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger Is not able to produce documentation for HTTP "PATCH"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585774/swagger-is-not-able-to-produce-documentation-for-http-patch)

Comment: Can you post your method/interface signatures including annotations?

Comment: @Helen - Added missing swagger config. There isn't any more configuration. Spring boot magic :)